# How to do Query in DynamoDB on the basis of HashKey and range Key?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to `DynamoDb` stuff. I just want to know how can we query on a table in DynamoDB with the `hashKey` and `rangeKey`.

Let's say my Table is `TestTable` and it's schema is something like this:

```
1.Id (HK of type String)
2 Date (RK of type String )
3 Name (attribute of type String)
```

Now If I want to query on this table on the basis of `hashKey` which is `Id` here, we make a `query` as :

Let's say my query is to get all Items having `Id ="123".`

```
TestTable testTable = new TestTable();
testTable.setId("123");

DynamoDBQueryExpression<TestTable> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<TestTable>()
                                                                .withHashKeyValues(TestTable)
                                                                .withConsistentRead(false);
```

Now I want to get all Items having `Id ="123" and Date ="1234"`.

How can I query this thing in `DynamoDB`

I am using `java` as my programming language.

Answer (score 15):

I wrote an article about DynamoDB queries and indexing using the AWS Java SDK some time ago: **http://labs.journwe.com/2013/12/15/dynamodb-secondary-indexes/**

In your case, it should work like this (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaQueryScanORMModelExample.html):

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

String hashKey = "123";
long twoWeeksAgoMilli = (new Date()).getTime() - (15L*24L*60L*60L*1000L);
Date twoWeeksAgo = new Date();
twoWeeksAgo.setTime(twoWeeksAgoMilli);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String twoWeeksAgoStr = dateFormatter.format(twoWeeksAgo);            
Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString())
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(twoWeeksAgoStr.toString()));

Reply replyKey = new Reply();
replyKey.setId(hashKey);

DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply>()
        .withHashKeyValues(replyKey)
        .withRangeKeyCondition("ReplyDateTime", rangeKeyCondition);

List<Reply> latestReplies = mapper.query(Reply.class, queryExpression);
```

Check out the Java Object Persistence Model section of the DynamoDB docs for more info.

Comment: Hey.. I have read your article already... It is indeed a nice one.Actually I don't want to make such condition for range key operation. Isn't there any other way ?

Comment: The other possibibility that I see (but have not tried, yet) is to use the low-level Java query api: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html `QuerySpec().withKeyConditionExpression("Id = :v_id and Date = :v_date").withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":v_id", "123") .withString(":v_date", "1234")`

Comment: If you're the author of the article, please can you fix the broken link?

Answer (score 8):

You could use dynamoDbMapper.load() as following:

```
TestTable testTable = new TestTable();
testTable.setId("123");
testTable.setDate("1234");
TestTable result = dynamoDBMapper.load(testTable);
```

Comment: What is returned when the value is not found on the table? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using index, you should have exact one item, if any, whose `Id ="123"` and `Date ="1234"`.

For the exact hash key and range key (in case of `=` operator), you don't need a query operation. Please have a loot at `GetItem` API, which is nifty. See [documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html).

And if you need non-EQ operator for range key (e.g. `>=`), you can use [key condition expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression) in `Query` operation: `Id = :id and Date >= :date`.